# Responsive Navbar using CSS no Bootstrap

Tags: html, css

I'm relatively new to coding and I've researched this topic and can't find an answer that fully fixes my issue of creating a responsive navbar. I've used the @media screen query in my #CSS and it works to an point, but then my navbar begins to stack up vertically rather then scale down while keeping its postion. Here is what I have for code:

```css
body{
 background: url('alt_largemouthbass.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
 background-size: cover;
 background-color:black;
 font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive, arial;
}

.navigation{
 text-align:center; 
}



ul.navbar{
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
 list-style-type:none;
 display:inline-block;
 
}

.navbar li{
 float:left;
 width:300px;
 height:50px;
 background-color:black;
 text-align:center;
 line-height:50px;
 opacity:.8;
 border:solid white 1px;
 text-shadow:2px 2px 2px white; 
}

.navbar li ul {
 display:block;
 position:relative;
 left:-41px;
 
 
}


.navbar li ul li{
 border:solid white 1px;
 display:none; 
 border-radius:15px;
}


.navbar li a{
 text-decoration:none;
 display:block;
 position:relative;
} 

.navbar li ul a:hover{    
 background-color:grey;
}

.navbar li:hover ul li{
 display:block;
 overflow:hidden;
 -webkit-border-radius:15px;

}

a{     
 color:green;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size:30px;
 padding-bottom:.5px;
 padding-top:.25px
 
}

@media screen and (max-width:1200px){
 .navigation{
  width:100%;
 }
 .navbar li{
  width:25%;
  
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial scale=1.0">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatic+SC" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Lorem Ipsom docnectuer</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="experiment.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="navigation">
<ul class="navbar">
 <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">ispum</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href="#">Lorem</a>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to make the navbar scale down while retaining its position and drop down menus. It currently works when I scale the browser down approx 20-50px but any more shrinking and it stacks the navbar vertically and the the dropdown menus become blocked by the parent li/ parent element. On a phone the viewport is so small I'm sure they would have to stack vertically and then I would end up using some sort of z-index and some conditions. But I'm currently trying to solve this problem with html and CSS. Everything I've seen has pointed to using bootstrap. Any and all assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: because I figured that others that use bootstrap may know of a work around

Comment: There's a lot of problems with your code. For instance, you have used .navbar li which doesnt just target the li directly inside navbar but all the inner nested li as well which messes up when shrinked further. If you want to target some specific element just directly inside use .navbar > li. Second, use display:flex on your navbar to make it flexible for all resolutions.

Comment: @dference my apologies if I have not used this forums use of tags properly. This is my first day using this forum as you can see from my profile. It has since been edited.

Comment: @Highdef thanks for the help. I'm currently teaching myself. I will make the changes and report back.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sure, no problem. Thanks for editing!

Comment: @Highdef I've made the changes that you stated. Now when I set display:flex to the navbar it move the navbar to the left rather then keeping it centered. I then tried setting the margin to auto assuming that this would correct its alignment but it didn't. However, I do not want to get rid of the display:flex as it only works when I set the display to flex. You've stated that there's a lot of problems with my code. Could you point out more as I'm trying to learn as much as possible as fast as possible. Many Thanks.

Comment: It's actually easy to align items as needed with flexbox and it makes it clean and responsive as well. I think this is the most basic stuff you need to know right now to get started with it . https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp Other than that, like I pointed out before, you're using .navbar li which targets every li inside the navbar. You can make use of classes or .navbar > li for directly accesing it.

Comment: @Highdef thanks for the information. I've been looking it over and from the quick review. I believe that this will solve all of my current issues. I will delve into this further and readjust my code accordingly and get back to you. I believe this answers the questions that have been having with flex-flow, and flex-wrap. Thanks agian.

Comment: @Goobi No problem :) Happy coding

Comment: @Goobi W3Schools has a good guide https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp